# Left Join not working with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two counters, one for units, one for waste.
 I need to pull the sum of the timers and separate by Year.
 The Left Join kinda works to get the combined, but as soon as I put a where condition to separate the timers, the think falls apart.
 **Could someone please check this out and give point me in the right direction?**
 Thanks.
 Jamie.

```
 SELECT year(counts.ts) as SalesYear, Q1.Res1 AS units, Q2.Res2 as rate
 FROM 
 (counts
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT (counts.ts), SUM(counts.count) AS Res1 
 FROM counts where counts.`name` = 104 and counts.count > 0 ) AS Q1 ON (counts.ts) = Q1.ts) 

 LEFT JOIN (SELECT (counts.ts), Sum(counts.count) AS Res2
 FROM counts where counts.`name` = 107 and counts.count > 0) AS Q2 ON (counts.ts) = Q2.ts

 GROUP BY year(counts.ts)
 order by year(counts.ts)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: typo in From clause ?? some error or empty result ?

Comment: btw: remove the opening parenthesis in the first from clause `FROM (counts` it's not required or doing anything useful

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use "conditional aggregates" like this:

```
SELECT
      YEAR(counts.ts) as SalesYear
    , SUM(case when counts.count = 104 then counts.count else 0 end) AS Res1 
    , SUM(case when counts.count = 107 then counts.count else 0 end) AS Res2
FROM counts 
WHERE counts.name IN (104,107)
      AND counts.count > 0 
GROUP BY YEAR(counts.ts) 
ORDER BY YEAR(counts.ts)
;
```

---

As sample data has now been provided via a sqlfiddle instance, the following is now relevant. Note that the query above, like the query is the question, the conditions were incorrectly based on the column `counts.count` instead of `counts.name`. Once that is corrected the exact same query structure provides a result. (Please take note that I could not have known this without seeing the data.)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e9a9/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `counts`;
CREATE TABLE `counts` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UniqueDataIndex` (`name`,`ts`,`count`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=475152 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475026', '107             ', '2015-01-27 10:18:00', '40');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475032', '104             ', '2015-01-27 10:20:00', '11');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475039', '107             ', '2015-01-27 10:22:00', '109');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475046', '104             ', '2015-01-27 10:24:00', '92');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475052', '107             ', '2015-01-27 10:26:00', '124');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475058', '104             ', '2016-01-27 10:28:00', '98');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475069', '107             ', '2016-01-27 10:32:00', '77');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475075', '104             ', '2016-01-27 10:34:00', '44');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475081', '107             ', '2016-01-27 10:36:00', '43');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475087', '104             ', '2016-01-27 10:38:00', '89');
INSERT INTO `counts` VALUES ('475093', '107             ', '2016-01-27 10:40:00', '89');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      YEAR(counts.ts) as SalesYear
    , SUM(case when counts.name = '104' then counts.count else 0 end) AS Res1 
    , SUM(case when counts.name = '107' then counts.count else 0 end) AS Res2
FROM counts 
WHERE counts.name IN ('104','107')
      AND counts.count > 0 
GROUP BY YEAR(counts.ts) 
ORDER BY YEAR(counts.ts)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e9a9/2/0)**:

```
| SalesYear | Res1 | Res2 |
|-----------|------|------|
|      2015 |  103 |  273 |
|      2016 |  231 |  209 |
```

Comment: apologies, had connection issues, it should have used `IN (104,107)` I had  not replaced an equals symbol

Comment: Note that while your code is more portable, in MySQL you can simply use SUM(x = 104) syntax

Comment: @Strawberry thanks one could alos use IF() ; I simply prefer the self documenting nature of case expressions as well as their applicability in most sql dbms

Comment: Thanks very much for your efforts guys but it still doesn't work. Result gives output for 2015 and 2016 but 2015 is inaccurate and 2016 reads 0.

Comment: Without data we have no clue what would cause your issues. in the question add "sample data" and "expected result" (dont use a comment for that) or setup a http://sqlfiddle.com and give us the url

Comment: Excellent! Now you should understand the power of "sample data" and "expected result" in your questions.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks and well done for cracking that for me. I actually wanted to add another result column which I thought would be easy but I can't figure it. I need to find the difference between the two results. Can you have another look please? I have updated the squiddle.